# NSManagedObject Core Data - request for member 'attribute name' in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Scenario:

I created a xcode project called "Importing" which I read an XML file in and import content into my core data database. I then have a second "main" project where I add the SQLite file into the main bundle and import using the code from Core Data Books example. I made changes to the .xcodedatamodel in my "importing" project I revealed that in finder and dragged it into my "main" project then generate the NSManagedObject model files there. Until now this has work but Xcode seems to be confused...

Recently I deleted some Attributes and added 1 new one. I then did the same process as above and now it says "request for member *'attribute name*' in something not a structure or union". If I type article *'modelname.'* and press esc the intellisence is still picking up the old attributes?

In the "importing" project though everything is working fine and I do not get any errors on any attributes and the intellisence is correct?

Please advice, is there a cache in xcode? I have used "Clean all targets" but this does not seem to work.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it this morning.

After taking fluchtpunkt's tip to do a search in project I used finder to search for one of the old attribute names and one of the NSManagedObject class files still appeared in the "Classes" folder. The one in xcode was outside the classes folder and had the correct attributes but even though xcode did not have a reference to the old file in the "classes" directory it was still using it... So deleted it and now it is working!

Bloody xcode and file references and groups - wish there was an alternative!

Thanks for all the ideas!

James

Answer (score 1):

Did you changed the properties in your custom NSManagedObject subclass?
Sounds like you forgot to do that.

Did you do a search in the whole project for your attribute name? If I had to make a guess I would say it is declared somewhere.

Comment: I did regenerate the NSManagedObject subclass files. These are correct BUT xcode intellisence is still picking up the old attributes? tried searching the whole project and not picking up anything...

Answer (score 0):

After making changes to xcdatamodel you need to do the following so try this

select your .xcdatamodel file.Then,

**Step-1:**

Go to **Design** -> **Data Model** -> **Add Model Version**

**Step-2:**

Go to **Design** -> **Data Model** -> **Set Current Version**

Now in "Set Current Version" you will get the latest one working for you.

Compile and Run. :]

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually there is no need to do this. Model Versions are only needed if you want to upgrade existing databases. Changes in the Data Model work fine without creating extra model versions, but you'll get the well known `The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`-Error at application startup

Comment: btw, you should add another model version **before** doing any changes

Comment: fluchtpunkt, Jodm has said that he made changes to his xcdatamodel file. So I suggested him to try to make a version to the best of my knowledge. :]

Comment: I made changes to the xcdatamodel outside of the project that is causing me problems. In the project I am doing importing in I made the changes, deleted the app from the simulator so I did not get any errors about the model becoming incompatible. I did the import, then moved the xcodedatamodel to the other project. The importing project is fine, the other project is still picking up the old attributes? I will try this in the morning but what is confusing me the most is one project is working and 1 isn't?